# Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'BACKUP'

Tags: sql, sql-server

Estoy haciendo un sp para respaldos diarios pero me manda el siguiente error

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'BACKUP'

Este es el comando, lo he hecho antes sin las variables y sin problema, pero ahora manda este error.

```
Create Procedure [dbo].[sp_RespaldoDiario]

    As
    Begin
    DECLARE @query VARCHAR(MAX)
    DECLARE @db VARCHAR(255)
    DECLARE @archivo VARCHAR(255)
    DECLARE @fecha VARCHAR(255)
    SET @db = 'QualitzPrueba'
    SET @fecha = CONVERT(varchar,getdate(), 112)
    SET @archivo = 'C:\'+@db+'_backup_'+@fecha+'.bak'
    SET @query

    BACKUP DATABASE @db TO DISK = @archivo
    WITH NOFORMAT, NOINIT, NAME = N'YourDB-Full Database Backup',
    SKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD, STATS = 10

    BEGIN TRY
    EXEC(@query)
```

Comment: Podrias mostrar con que valores lo estas haciendo?

Comment: @EdgarVazquez Listo

Comment: SET @query no le estas asigando nada asi como lo pones esta bien?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hola amigo prueba con algo como esto.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_RespaldoDiario]
    AS
    Begin
    DECLARE @query VARCHAR(MAX)
    DECLARE @db VARCHAR(255)
    DECLARE @archivo VARCHAR(255)
    DECLARE @fecha VARCHAR(255)
    SET @db = 'QualitzPrueba'
    SET @fecha = CONVERT(varchar,getdate(), 112)
    SET @archivo = 'C:\'+@db+'_backup_'+@fecha+'.bak'
    SET @query='

    BACKUP DATABASE '+@db+' TO DISK = '''+@archivo+'''
    WITH NOFORMAT, NOINIT, NAME = N''YourDB-Full Database Backup'',
    SKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD, STATS = 10'

    EXEC(@query)
    END
```

El detalle pienso que esta en que no concatenaste correctamente la variable @query de esta forma en la que te lo pongo debería funcionar.
Checalo y andamos aquí.

Saludos

Comment: Funciono perfecto ... Muchas gracias!

Comment: De nada. Saludos